# azure PHP zend framework require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, azure, zend-framework

I am calling this PHP code `require_once 'PDFMerger/fpdf/fpdf.php';` inside Zend Framework controller action. This is working fine locally, but it is not working on Azure Web App.

This is the Full Path:

*D:\home\site\wwwroot\library\PDFMerger\fpdf\fpdf.php*

This is my get_include_path() result:

*D:\home\site\wwwroot\library;.;C:\php\pear*

This is PHP Log Message:

*[23-Sep-2017 14:12:42 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PDFMerger/fpdf/fpdf.php' (include_path='D:\home\site\wwwroot\application/../library;D:\home\site\wwwroot\library;.;C:\php\pear')*

This is my PHP code:

```
public function auditEmailPdfAction(){

        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        try{
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            $values = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $filename = $this->getAuditSnapshot($values['audit_id']);
            $logged_in_user = new \Zend_Session_Namespace('logged_in_user');
            $userEntity = $this->em->getRepository('\Ia\Entity\User')->find($logged_in_user->id);

            require_once 'PDFMerger/fpdf/fpdf.php';

            $pdf = new \FPDF;
...
```

I have tried using different path and still returning the same error. I hope you guys have any suggestions.

Comment: it looks like you are mixing Slash and Backslash in the path .. usually not a big deal but you can try http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php on your `get_include_path()` and see what you get in return

Comment: I would recommend to give it the full path if possible. Use `__DIR__` to get the directory from the file where your "auditEmailPdfAction" function is placed. Then from there, go to your PDFMerger/fpdf/fpdf.php directly. Something like: `require_once __DIR__ . "/PDFMerger/fpdf/fpdf.php";`